# through hole or SMD capacitor for high voltage powers

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

When TH and SMD caps are avalilable with same spec, which one to prefer for high voltage powers.?

Comment: To be more precise my question is, from the power supply i use a capacitor (0.1 uF, 450v rating) connected in parallel to the power supply. Caps with this spec is available as TH and SMD. Usualy for small capacitance value we use SMD caps, but in this application TH is recomended. Why should I prefer TH instead of SMD when the voltage rating for caps is 450v, is there any relation with high voltage and caps selection..?

Answer (score 3):

If two components have the **same spec,** then your preference should be based on (but not limited to) the following:

- Which component is less expensive?
- Which one can I solder more easily?
- Do I need to save space on the board by using SMD?
- Do I have height requirements or something that dictates usage of SMD?
- Which component will cost less to place if doing a large production run?
- Which component is more likely to be available long term, if that's a concern?

If the components are the same spec, then either should be just as viable for the rated high voltage application.

Comment: Thanks fo the detailed information.If reliability is a concern, which one will suit the best for high voltage  rating. TH or SMT..?

Comment: Reliability is linked to manufacturer quality, stated operating tolerances (in the datasheet), and environment where the device will be operated. If the board is going to be exposed, I'd probably favor SMD because a through-hole component, being larger, might be more vulnerable to being bent over, etc.